# Parse number from textbox including decimal place / output with 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, decimal

I have been a non member stalker on here for a while now and it is very valuable! Thank you!

I am stuck though and would like some advice.

I am making a simple calculator that calculates Blackjack payouts on a button press but I cannot make it show decimal places. I would like it to show 2 decimal places on output.

the code I am using is below:

```
private void GO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int TextBoxnumber;
    int BJwin;
    int BJwinTotal;
    int win;
    int wintotal;
    TextBoxnumber = int.Parse( textBox1.Text);
    BJwin = TextBoxnumber + (TextBoxnumber / 2);
    BJwinTotal = TextBoxnumber + BJwin;
    win = TextBoxnumber;
    wintotal = TextBoxnumber + TextBoxnumber;
    textBox2.Text = BJwin.ToString(); 
    textBox3.Text = BJwinTotal.ToString() ;
    textBox5.Text = win.ToString();
    textBox6.Text = wintotal.ToString();
}
```

Any help or advice would be wonderful as I am really getting nowhere with string formatting...

Thank you in advance!

Chris

Comment: instead of using, int you just use decimal datatype like decimal d1= 0.00m;

Comment: `.ToString("0.00")` ?

Comment: Math.Round(double.Parse(textBox1.Text),2); But textBox1.Text must be in right format

Comment: ("0.00") adding this adds ".00" to the output regardless of the actual result.  I figures it was because numbers had already been rounded up at calculation...?

Comment: `textBox2.Text = BJwin.ToString() + ".00"` ? Just add?

Comment: Don't use int, use float or decimal

Comment: "`("0.00")` adding this adds `".00"`" because you're doing decimal calculations with integer variables -- which do not store the decimal part.

Comment: Don't use int, use float or decimal - Thank you so much Furtiro - I feel like a fool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `decimal` variables to get fractional results:

```
private void GO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal TextBoxnumber;
    decimal BJwin;
    decimal BJwinTotal;
    decimal win;
    decimal wintotal;
    TextBoxnumber = decimal.Parse( textBox1.Text);
    BJwin = TextBoxnumber + (TextBoxnumber / 2);
    BJwinTotal = TextBoxnumber + BJwin;
    win = TextBoxnumber;
    wintotal = TextBoxnumber + TextBoxnumber;
    textBox2.Text = BJwin.ToString("0.00"); 
    textBox3.Text = BJwinTotal.ToString("0.00") ;
    textBox5.Text = win.ToString("0.00");
    textBox6.Text = wintotal.ToString("0.00");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much